# Flexbox footer not stacking under other divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I created a layout using css and Flexbox, the issue is the footer div displays at the bottom of the page on load, but content shoots past it, so when you scroll the footer is just floating in the middle of the page. I'm not sure what to change.

I have changed the footer to be sticky, and bottom to be 0px. It kinda worked with adjusting the margin of the other divs, but its not very clean. I was hoping to keep using the flexbox attributes and just have them stack, but that doesn't seem to work? I've also adjusted the min-max heights of the other divs, but as soon as the window shrinks past the min height the footer just floats over the rest of the content.

Link to code [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47veytfo/1/)

```
.footer{
height:40px;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
width:100%;
background-color:purple;
}
```

I would suspect that the footer would obey the stacking order and just display under the rest of the content, like the main body does under the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the height set on your '.content' class. Change `height: calc(100vh - 100px)` to `min-height: calc(100vh - 100px)`

Unless you want the footer and header always visible, then you can just add `overflow: auto` to make the content scroll

Comment: My gosh that was so dang simple. Thank you for that answer! Works exactly as it should now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height: calc(100vh - 100px);` from `.content` class

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.bodywrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  
  background-color: black;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: brown;
}
.hleft {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.hmid {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow:1;
  font-size: calc(1.5vw);
  background-color: orange;
}
.hright {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: pink;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: darkblue;
}
.lmenu {
  display: flex;
  width: 250px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ltop {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.lmid {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
.lbot {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.rmaincont {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: calc(100vw - 250px);
  background-color: grey;
}
.note {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
}
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  min-height: 550px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
.footer {
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Mid-Valley Intranet</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cstyle.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="bodywrap">

    <header class="header">
      <div class="hleft">Left</div>
      <div class="hmid">Mid</div>
      <div class="hright">Right</div>
    </header>

    <div class="content">
      <div class="lmenu">
        <div class="ltop">
          Top
        </div>
        <div class="lmid">
          Mid
        </div>
        <div class="lbot">
          Bot
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="rmaincont">
        <div class="note">
          Notice
        </div>
        <div class="main">
          Main Content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
      Footer Text
    </footer>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things did to do to make this work:

- Originally the scrolling was happening on the body. I added `overflow: hidden` on the body and `overflow-y: auto` to the div with the "bodywrap" class.
- I added the position sticky and bottom 0, but with vendor prefixes:

```
bottom: 0;
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: -moz-sticky;
position: -ms-sticky;
position: -o-sticky;
```

- I also made the div with class "bodywrap" have a height equal to 100vh minus the height of the footer (so that the scrolling content doesn't get cutoff at the bottom). You may want to set a sass variable or something for this 40px height.

```
height: calc(100vh - 40px);
```

Here's a demo of the new version:

[jsfiddle.net/webwhizjim/6f84b7su/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/webwhizjim/6f84b7su/3/)